# Changing Package.json packages depending on how the project is used

Tags: node.js, module, electron, package

Hi I am trying to find out if there is a way to add remove packages automatically depending on how the project is used.

Example.
I have a program which is an express app, wrapped in electron to become a desktop application.
But I also use that same express application as a service on Azure and local linux installs.

When I do the cloud and local linux services, it installs all the packages from the package.json, including the electron packages which are not needed for these and take up space unnecessarily.

Is there a way I can dynamically add or remove the electron packages depending on how they are used. Also I have two JS files that start the express server JS file. One for desktop using electron package, and the other JS file does not.

Cheers Mitchell

Answer (score 0):

For those kind of things, I recommend you to take a look at pnpm (https://pnpm.io/).
PNPM is a solution for monorepos. It means that you will have a single package.json for several projects on a single repository and it will manage which package to use in which project and it will keep every dependency to the same version.

Cheers Antoine